# Layout Expression - Ternary Operation for drawable value

Tags: android, android-layout

vm has a `isWin` value which can have only `0` or `1`.

I'd like to take advantage of `Data Binding` for this.

I access `vm` in the `<data>` and I connected like this:

```
@{vm.isWin == 1 ? @drawable/win_true : @drawable/win_false}
```

However, this seems doesn't work.

I get this with red underline:

```
'!=', '%', '==', '(', ..., '>=', '>>' or '>>>' expected, got ':'
```

[This](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#imports_variables_and_includes) is reference by Google.

full `activity_main.xml` is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="io.monolabs.asscnfc.vm.ResultViewModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src = "@{vm.isWin == 1 ? @drawable/win_true : @drawable/win_false}"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had also face this issue. resolved by removing 'is' keyword from variable name.javabeans trying generate same name getter and setter. As 'is' comes before method name only.